# aws s3 mv/sync command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have about 2 million files nested in subfoldrs in a bucket and want to move all of them to another bucket. Spending much of time on searching ... i found a solution to use AWS CLI mv/sync command. use move command or use sync command and then delete all the files after successfully synced.

`aws s3 mv s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket2/ --recursive`

or it can be as

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket2/
```

But the problem is how would i know that how many files/folders have moved or synced and how much time would it take...
And what if some exception occurs(machine/server stops/ internet disconnection due to any reason )...i have to again execute the command or it will for surely complete and move/sync all files. How can i be sure about the number of files moved/synced and files not moved/synced.

or can i have something like that

I move limited number of files  e.g 100 thousand.. and repeat until all files are moved...

or move files on the basis of uploaded time.. e.g files uploaded from starting date to ending date

if yes .. how?

Comment: Have you tried it?  `aws s3 sync` *should* be safely interruptible and should pick up where it left off if you restart it. It's essentially impossible to copy part of a single object in S3 -- at the object level, either the entire copy succeeds intact or the new bucket won't have that object at all.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  ... i cant try as files are too much and how would i know how much files have been synced.... is there a way so i can know how much files have been synced ... before restarting it

Comment: Have you tried it?  I believe it displays the keys as it proceeds and they are done in lexical order.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot.. i have tried to run with some files (about 100) and it worked fine... it displayed output ...while syncing from one bucket to another... at the end it does not show any count of files mooved and for my actual data to be moved... how can i see output of million of files?

Answer (score 4):

To sync them use:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket2/
```

You can repeat the command, after it finish (or fail) without issue. This will check if anything is missing/different to the target s3 bucket and will process it again.

The time depends on what size are the files, how much objects you have. Amazon counts directories as an object, so they matter too.

Comment: This command works well with folder structure as well. Thank you for helping!!